# Can't understand why this cache dir keeps appearing

Tags: debugging, rust, caching, ethereum, solidity

All of my repositories located at /Users/matthewpryor/projects/ seem to have a directory that continuously appears, not sure where from... it seems it has to do with [ethers-rs](https://github.com/gakonst/ethers-rs)? NOTE: ethers-rs is in the process of being deprecated.

GOAL: I would like to stop this cache dir and json file from appearing. I have to untrack it from git each time it appears. I delete the directory and if I close and re-open VSCode, it will reappear.

The file and dirname: `cache/solidity-files-cache.json`

Contents of the json file:

```json
{
  "_format": "ethers-rs-sol-cache-3",
  "paths": {
    "artifacts": "out",
    "build_infos": "out/build-info",
    "sources": "src",
    "tests": "test",
    "scripts": "script",
    "libraries": ["node_modules"]
  },
  "files": {}
}
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening or solutions are greatly appreciated!

I have tried deleting Ethereum-related Rust directories, for example [trin](https://github.com/ethereum/trin).

Pretty confused why it's happening. I have probably configured something wrong a long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I disabled "Foundry Test Explorer v0.0.1" extension in vs code and problem solved.

Hope it works.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Thank you so much, I really appreciate it!